# dynamic creation of select tag in jsp using jstl and arraylist

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

I have searched this forum and net for this, found many example but still i am not able to populate the select box in jsp.

I have written a jsp servlet, where servlet returns an arraylist and in jsp uhsing jstl i am trying to create a select box and populating option with arraylist values.

Following is my code.

Servlet Code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    UserService userService = new UserServiceImpl();
    try {
        String[] questions = userService.getQNA().getQuestions();
        List<String> ques = new ArrayList<String>();
        ques = Arrays.asList(questions);
        request.setAttribute("questionDTO", ques);
        response.sendRedirect("forms/enrollMigrationUser.jsp");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("request failed "+ e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

JSP code :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Enroll Migration Users</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="/nycb/enrolluser" name="enrollForm">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>User setup</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>UserId :</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="userName" id="userName"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Password :</td>
        <td><input type="password" name="password" id="password"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="computerType" value="public">Authorize this computer</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <select name='role'>
                <c:forEach items="<%=request.getAttribute(\"questionDTO\") %>" var="question">
                    <option value="<c:out value="${question}"/>"><c:out value="${question}"/></option>
                </c:forEach>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="qna6" id="qna6"/></td>
    </tr>

<tr>
        <td>
            <select name='role'>
                <c:forEach items="${questionDTO}" var="question">
                    <option value="<c:out value="${question}"/>"><c:out value="${question}"/></option>
                </c:forEach>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="qna6" id="qna6"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="click" name="dropdown" id="dropdown">
</form>
```

I am not able to populate the select box, the option field is empty.

Can anyone please let me know where i am going wrong?

Comment: What's the problem? What is it supposed to do? What does it actually do? Why does it do that?

Comment: I have edited the question, the issue is, i am not able to populate the select box option field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sendRedirect()` creates a new request and any attribute set in request will not be available in redirected JSP page.

Try any one

1. You can use `RequestDispatcher#forward` or `RequestDispatcher#include` in this case.
2. You can save it in `session` as attribute.

Sample code:

```
RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("forms/enrollMigrationUser.jsp");
view.forward(request, response);
```

OR

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("questionDTO", ques);
response.sendRedirect("forms/enrollMigrationUser.jsp");
```

---

Always try to avoid *Scriplet elements* instead use JSTL & EL.

You can do in this to read an attribute from any scope in order page, request, session and finally applicaion

```
<c:forEach items="${questionDTO}" var="question">
```

OR read from specific scope.

```
<c:forEach items="${requestScope.questionDTO}" var="question">
```